# Get two values ​in select React

Tags: reactjs

I need to change the value of a select (Setor), according to another select (Usuario), the Usuario select contains an attribute called (codsetor), and this codsetor will be the value of the select (Setor)

I tried this way, but it doesn't exist, I can even do it another way but it's an ugly code, I wanted an easy and clean way

```
<Form.Select
  value={Usuario}
   onChange={(e) => setUsuario(e.target.value)}
   >
    <option selected key={0} value={0}>
       Escolha o Usuario
    </option>
        {UsuariosBD && (
          UsuariosBD.map((usuario, index) => (
            <option selected={Usuario == usuario.codigo} key={index}
            value={`${usuario.codigo},${usuario.codsetor}`}>
             {usuario.nome}
               </option>
               ))
                 )}
</Form.Select>

<Form.Select
       value={Setor}
     onChange={(e) => setSetor(e.target.value)}>
        <option disabled selected={!Setor} key={0} value={0}>
         Setor
           </option>
             {SetorBD && (
                  SetorBD.map((setor, index) => (
                      <option disabled selected={Setor == setor.codigo} key={index}
                         value={setor.codigo}>
                         {setor.setor}
                      </option>
            ))
             )}
            </Form.Select>
```

And in the Usuario State change, I did this

```
if(Usuario.includes(',')) {
        let valores = Usuario.split(',')
        setUsuario(valores[0])
        setSetor(valores[1])
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

Either you may have to call setSetor method in the onChange event of the Usuario Select method(pull out the method to a function and do both update). This way both will update at the same time. (You will have to take value from event since the Usuario value would not have been updated by this time)

or you may have a useEffect with the Usuario as dependency and there you call setSetor (at this time the value of Usuario will be available)